# Angular Routes (tutorial) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am following google's angular tutorial log (different names for stuff I need), and I cannot get the routing to work correctly for the life of me.  If I take the # out of the hrefs, i'll get a "Cannot GET" error".  With the #, the URL changes but nothing happens.

controllers.js

```
var AppControllers = angular.module('AppControllers',[]);

AppControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('javascripts/apprentices.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.apprentices = data;

  });
  $scope.orderProp = 'semester';
}]);

AppControllers.controller('apprenticeCtrl',['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
console.dir('hi');
      $http.get('javascripts/person.json').success(function(data) {
        // $scope.apprentices = data;
      });
    }]);
```

app.js

```
var App = angular.module('App',[
  'ngRoute',
  'AppControllers']);

App.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/apprentices', {
        templateUrl: 'views/apprentice.html',
        controller: 'apprenticeCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        templateUrl:'../views/home/index.html',
                redirectTo: '/asfsfsf'
      });
  }]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="javascripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <body>
      <div ng-app="App">
        <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
          code
      </div>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: The element that has `ng-app` tag must contains `<div ng-view></div>` for `ngRoute` to work

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to move the ng-app tag up to the body element. The scope of the app is defined in the ng-app element and not it's siblings:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="javascripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="App">
      <div>
        <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
          code
      </div>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Another option would be to put the ng-view div inside the ng-app div if so desired.

Comment: That fixed my initial error, thank you. Now it's telling me 404 cant find my files when the route changes.                               GET http://localhost:3000/views/apprentice.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I do not know your directory structure, but it looks like in your templateUrls you have ```views/apprentice.html``` for apprentice which is different than ```../views/``` for the index.html.